# Not able to remove SharePointPnP module

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

I installed "SharePointPnPPowerShell2016" module sometime back when I was doing some research around PnP PowerShell.

Today I was trying to install "SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline" and got an error message which says commands are already installed. Because I already have "SharePointPnPPowerShell2016" module which comes with similar commands I could not install "SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline".

So in order to remove this module, I ran "Remove-Module" and got below error.

> Remove-Module : No modules were removed. Verify that the specification
>   of modules to remove is correct and those modules exist in the
>   runspace. At line:1 char:1
>   + Remove-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell2016
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Remove-Module], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_NoModulesRemoved,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveModuleCommand

When I was trying to see if a module is loaded or not I found out that "SharePointPnPPowerShell2016" is installed but not loaded.

See below screenshot for output for Get-Module and "Remove-Module" command.

[image]

Comment: how about running `Uninstall-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell2016`  and then installing the PnP PowerShell online ?

Comment: @GautamSheth That worked.

Comment: cool, have posted that as answer ! Could you please accept it, so that it gets removed from the unanswered section, thanks !?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to use the `Uninstall-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell2016` to remove the PnP PowerShell 2016.

After that you can install the PnP SharePoint Online powershell using the executable file or using the `Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline` command.

Download link - [PnP PowerShell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/releases)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do not install the "SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline" and "SharePointPnPPowerShell2016" in the same server.

You could install in the different servers.

More reference:

[SharePointPnP.PowerShell Commands.](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell)

And you could use “Uninstall-PnPAppInstance” command to remove the PNP PowerShell.

[Uninstall-PnPAppInstance.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/blob/master/sharepoint/sharepoint-ps/sharepoint-pnp/Uninstall-PnPAppInstance.md)